# Level shifter 3.3V to 5V

Tags: level-shifting

I want to translate a signal from 3.3V mcu to 5V to use it on WS2812B led. I don't want to use a BSS1338 because I have seen flickering issues with high frequencies.

I have found 74LVC1G125 but it seems that the signal should be at least 0.7xVCC so it wouldn't be reliable with 3.3V signal if VCC is 5V.
I also found SN74LVC1T45 which seems a good choice but is 4x times the price of the 74LVC1G125. Are there any cheap alternatives?

I might use the SN74LVC1T45 but I want to make sure how to connect it. I read that if DIR is grounded the direction is B > A, so I should use B as my 3.3V signal, Vccb=3.3V and Vcca=5V. Is this correct? What should I change if I want A > B? Should I just connect DIR directly to Vcca?

Comment: Use a chip with TTL compatible inputs, not low-voltage CMOS. A 74HCT or 74AHCT version ought to work.

Comment: Do a search here. I think many other questions like this but not exactly identical have been asked before, especially in context of addressable RGB LEDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 3.3 V happens to be near the output voltage of TTL circuits, so for this combination of voltages, you can use any buffer with TTL-compatible inputs, such as the (SN)74AHCT1G125/17.
- This is a unidirectional signal, so you can use a unidirectional translator like the TXU0101 or (SN)74LV1T125/34.
- You can use a translating transceiver like the (SN)74LVC1T45/SN74LXC1T45, but the ability to change the direction is more flexibility than you need here. (The DIR input is a normal digital input and indeed should be connected to ≥ V<sub>CCA</sub> or GND.)

Comment: I found SN74AHCT1G125DBVR on LCSC website. Is it as simple as connecting OE to GND, A as input and Y as output?

Comment: Yes. (The difference between the '125 and the '126 is that /OE is active-low and OE is active-high. Please do not call the control input of the '125 "OE".)